# How do I run directory-structured tests in phpunit?

Tags: php, phpunit, slim

The PHPUnit docs say that I can shove all my tests into a folder and run `phpunit` on the folder to execute them all in one go:

http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/organizing-tests.html

But when I try on my forked copy of Slim (https://github.com/codeguy/Slim) it doesn't work! I have installed PHPUnit via PEAR so I don't think there's anything odd about it.

Here's the output:

```
mark@ubuntu:/project/submodules/Slim$ phpunit tests     
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PHPUnit_Framework_Exception' with message 'Neither "tests.php" nor "tests.php" could be opened.' in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Skeleton/Test.php:102
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php(157): PHPUnit_Util_Skeleton_Test->__construct('tests', '')
#1 /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php(129): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(Array, true)
#2 /usr/bin/phpunit(49): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
#3 {main}
  thrown in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Skeleton/Test.php on line 102
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

-EDIT-

I'm using PHPUnit 3.5.15.

Here are the contents of the directories `Slim` and `tests`:

```
mark@ubuntu:/project/submodules/Slim$ ls -l 
total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 mark mark 4320 Aug 23 14:41 README.markdown
drwxr-xr-x 1 mark mark  408 Aug 24 02:39 Slim
-rw-r--r-- 1 mark mark 6993 Aug 23 14:41 index.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 mark mark 1398 Aug 23 14:41 logo.png
drwxr-xr-x 1 mark mark  476 Aug 23 14:41 tests
mark@ubuntu:/project/submodules/Slim$ ls -l tests
total 104
-rw-r--r-- 1 mark mark    73 Aug 23 14:41 Foo.php
drwxr-xr-x 1 mark mark   204 Aug 23 14:41 Http
-rw-r--r-- 1 mark mark  4398 Aug 23 14:41 LogTest.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 mark mark  5088 Aug 23 14:41 LoggerTest.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 mark mark   734 Aug 23 14:41 README
-rw-r--r-- 1 mark mark 11115 Aug 23 14:41 RouteTest.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 mark mark 10327 Aug 23 14:41 RouterTest.php
drwxr-xr-x 1 mark mark   102 Aug 23 14:41 Session
-rw-r--r-- 1 mark mark 47703 Aug 23 14:41 SlimTest.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 mark mark  6447 Aug 23 14:41 ViewTest.php
drwxr-xr-x 1 mark mark   102 Aug 23 14:41 logs
drwxr-xr-x 1 mark mark   102 Aug 23 14:41 templates
```

I've literally just forked Slim and cloned it, nothing fancy!

Comment: Can you paste the contents of the `Slim` and `tests` folders?

Comment: Works for me. What PHPUnit version is that?

Comment: It's PHPUnit v3.5.15. I will edit the question to include the contents of the folders. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this error is what you see when you specify a folder but the folder doesn't contain any files that match the pattern `*Test.php`.

This is NOT my problem, however. I'm running the tests from within a shared folder inside an Ubuntu VM using VirtualBox. This doesn't play well with PHPUnit, apparently. Or it might be PHP. Either way, it's incorrectly erroring because when I move the folder into a non-shared location inside the VM it works just fine.

**Edit**

I was running VirtualBox 4.1.0 which apparently has this problem. Upgrading to 4.1.2 fixed it and everything is running fine now. Thanks to everyone for their help.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you issue the `phpunit` command inside whichever folder contains `phpunit.xml` and/or `bootstrap.php`. My guess is that these are located inside the `tests` folder.

```
.../Slim$ cd tests
.../Slim/tests$ phpunit
```

Comment: Thanks! I've added the directory contents but unfortunately there isn't a `phpunit.xml` or a `bootstrap.php` in the `tests` folder. Any ideas? The Slim docs say all I need to run is `phpunit tests` from within the `Slim` directory...

Comment: Did you try the above commands to run from within the `tests` directory?

Comment: I did, yes, but it just fails :(